# How to use a parameter inside a parameter

Tags: jmeter

I have two user defined variables like this.

[image]

I want to use one variable value as the parameter name in the second parameter. In this case I want Teacher as the result.

I used it like this but not working.

(${__eval(${pName})

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use [__V function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__V). This returns the result of evaluating a variable name expression and can be used to evaluate nested variable references

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have `Teacher` value you need to use `${pDesig}` [JMeter Variable reference](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html):

[image]

In particular your case using [__eval() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__eval) is not required at all. The valid use case for the __eval() function is when you have JMeter Function or Variable coming from external data source, i.e. from [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) and want JMeter to **eval**uate the function or variable so it would be substituted with its respective value.

More information: [Here’s What to Do to Combine Multiple JMeter Variables](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/here%E2%80%99s-what-do-combine-multiple-jmeter-variables)